# How to get form details from FormResponse in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attaching a onSubmit() trigger programmatically to different forms in my google drive. The form submit event has to trigger an email to the owner of the form. How do i access the owner of the form in my handler function. Below is my handler function. The problem i am facing is, i could not get the form reference based on the formResponse object.

```
function formSubmit(event) {
  var formResponse=event.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var emailBody=formResponse.getRespondentEmail()+"has reponded to the form. Please click here    "+formResponse.toPrefilledUrl()+" to view the response";
  MailApp.sendEmail("owner@test.com", "Sample form submitted", emailBody);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `formSubmit` handler you can do `FormApp.getActiveForm().getId()` to get a reference to the the `Form` object itself. However, there is no good way to get access to the Form's owner.

You will have to rethink the usecase such that in some way you are able to grab the form owner's usecase when the form is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var editorEmail = FormApp.getActiveForm.getEditors()[0].getEmail();
```

This is not guaranteed to be the email address of the owner, but at least one of the editors' email addresses.